# How long should I wait until I help my crested gecko shed?

Tags: health, reptiles, geckos, shedding, molting

I am a new crested gecko owner and this is his first shed with me. It seems like all of his shed is off other than on his toes, but it’s only been about 30 minutes since he shed the rest. I know how to remove the shed, but I don’t know how long I should wait to help him.

Comment: His shed came off